# $_POST variable in chmod permissions

Tags: php

I wonder how to enter a $_POST variable to chmod permission :

I tried this way:

```
<?php 
    $file = 'myfile.txt';
    $permission = $_POST['permission'];
    chmod($file, $permission);
?>
```

Unfortunately $permission variable, does not work in chmod.

```
    $_POST['permission'] is '0755'
```

Is there any way to convert a variable to the correct format?

Comment: Shouldn't that just not work since it's a string?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php says it's very strict with whats acceptable.

Comment: use (int) before $_POST['permission']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use typecast:

**Code:**

```
  <?php 
    $file = 'myfile.txt';
    $permission = (int)$_POST['permission'];
    chmod($file, $permission);
  ?>
```

OR
 You can also use [**intval()**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function instead of (int)[typecasting].